# Using Dapper Extensions, can IDs be retrieved when inserting IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, dapper-extensions

If an object is inserted 1 at a time, then the Id can be fetched from the object:

```
foreach (var object in objectList)
{
    conn.Insert(object);
    int id = object.Id; // Returns Id as expected
}
```

However, if an IEnumerable of objects is inserted, the Ids cannot be fetched properly:

```
conn.Insert(objectList);
foreach (var object in objectList)
{
    int id = object.Id; // Returning 0
}
```

Is there a way to insert the list of objects and still get the Ids back without inserting 1 at a time?

Comment: Is this really [`Dapper`](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)? I don't know an `Insert` method.

Comment: You are right, it is Dapper Extensions. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like that has been implemented. See the code [here](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/blob/master/DapperExtensions/DapperImplementor.cs). I would assume this is for performance reasons.